# ELK: CSV reading by log stash is delayed

Tags: logstash, elk

I am new to ELK system and am trying to set up a system on my local windows  server 2016 r2 machine which has 256 GB RAM and processors 2. So I downloaded logstash, elasticSearch and kibana on my machine. 
The aim is that I have a lot of CSV files that I will get from a remote machine in a specific folder. Once I have those CSV files I wish to take out data from them and put them in elastic search. 
My logstash config is like this

```
# Sample Logstash configuration for creating a simple
# Beats -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch pipeline.


input {
    file {
        path=> "D:/File-upload-server/uploads/*.csv"
    }
}

filter{
    csv
    {
    separator => ","
    columns => ["PRODUCTID","cost","seller","buyer","address","city","state","pincode"]
    }
}

output {

elasticsearch
{
    hosts =>    ["localhost:9200"]
    index =>    ["mydata"]
}

}
```

When i see http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v , i find the entries like

```
health status index                 uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .kibana_task_manager  CD7ljRARROe-2YnvzYhbFw   1   0          2            0     29.5kb         29.5kb
yellow open   mydata               XmTpG5PrQT-c6dQrjkbjIg   1   1          7            0     31.1kb         31.1kb
green  open   .kibana_1             qhQ84QNvTSSrl0eRxvKj0g   1   0          5            1     32.5kb         32.5kb
```

Note that docs.count represents something which increases when a new file is pushed .

When a new file comes in the folder D:/File-upload-server/uploads , I find that the new file is picked after 20 minutes or so. The machine is not loaded at all. All resources are available to this setup.

what should be the ideal configuration or have i done wrong configuration .

Answer (score 0):

As the csv files are ready to be consumed from logstash, I suggest trying to open the files on "read" mode in order to read them until the EOF and continue looking for new upcoming csv files.
Due to the "tail" default mode, I suspect that it's waiting for specific amount of time until looking for next files.

```
input {
    file {
        path=> "D:/File-upload-server/uploads/*.csv"
        mode => "read"
    }
}
```